# Shortening a LEFT JOIN with two different conditions on same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the follow Query:

```
SELECT a.id FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT aid, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS workers FROM table_b WHERE lv = 1 GROUP BY aid
) b ON b.aid = a.id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT aid, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS writers FROM table_b WHERE lv = 2 GROUP BY aid
) c ON c.aid = a.id
```

I decided to make it shorter in a single `LEFT JOIN` by using `CASE .. WHEN .. THEN .. ELSE .. END`

by doing the following:

```
SELECT a.id FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT aid,
    CASE 
      WHEN lv = 1 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS workers
      WHEN lv = 2 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS writers
    END
    FROM table_b GROUP BY aid
) bc ON bc.aid = a.id
```

But it doesn't seem to work with the `Alias` inside. How can I shorten the `LEFT JOIN` in this case? Or do I just stick with the **two** `LEFT JOIN`s?

**Error**: `/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS workers WHEN lv = 2 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS writers END FROM table_b GROUP BY' at line 1 */`

P.S. The Query is `LIMIT 1`

Comment: you need to provide the alias `a` to your table `table_a`...

Comment: @Mittal added it now.

Comment: Now, Which error you have received?

Comment: @Mittal Added it to the Question now.

Comment: "But it doesn't seem to work with the Alias inside." Aliases are only possible on tables or on selected columns. " How can I shorten the LEFT JOIN in this case? Or do I just stick with the two LEFT JOINs?" Yes you need to use two LEFT JOIN's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SELECT 
   GROUP_CONCAT(case when lv = 1 then name end) as workers, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(case when lv = 2 then name end) as writers
 FROM table_b as b
 JOIN table_a as a ON a.id=b.aid
GROUP BY a.id
```

SQL Fidder demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/490931/1

Comment: Yes, it worked, I used `case when lv = 1 then (id,name) end` at first, But apparently I can only get a single column per `GROUP_CONCAT`.